# Create a new Journey or extend an old one?

Tags: journeybuilder

We do have a closed shop and when registered and accepted you are going through a Welcome Journey which lasts 14 days (picture 1 attached). So now we want for new Customers who never bought to get into a series of Emails in which he receives Vouchers to get the Customer to buying. So should we add it to the already existing Welcome journey or should we make a new one. The workload would be similar, and it is possible in both option does somebody know the pros and cons of Creating a new Journey in comparison to extending the old one.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try and keep it in the same journey since it's related to customer info and I believe it would be better to have all that info in 1 place i.e., a single data extension, What I would probably do as an extra measure, is to create a field/Boolean to identify new customers who skip that buying process, so in the future you can easily identify those customers